# OS system calls from bash script

Tags: bash, shell, system-calls

Is it possible to call OS system calls like `open`, `close` etc from a shell script? I tried googling but it takes me in the wrong direction of using the `system()` command. Can some one help on this?

Comment: Why not just use the normal mechanisms for dealing with files?

Answer (score 10):

Many syscalls are accessible, but only via the native shell mechanisms, rather than being able to directly specify exact parameters. For instance:

```
exec 4>outfile
```

calls:

```
open("outfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 4)
```

(with `3` being replaced by the next available descriptor), and

```
exec 4<&-
```

calls:

```
close(4)
```

Some shells, such as bash, allow additional builtins to be added through loadable modules (see the `enable` builtin, used to load such modules); if you *really* needed functionality not provided upstream, you could potentially implement it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system. For example AIX has a [`syscall` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=s-syscall-command) for this

```
syscall [ -n ] Name [ Argument1 ... ArgumentN ] [  ; Name [ Argument1 ... ArgumentN ] ] ...
```

Plan9 also has a [similar command](https://www.unix.com/man-page/plan9/1/syscall/):

```
syscall [ -o ] entry [ arg ...  ]
```

---

On Linux there's no such command but there's [mauri870/syscall](https://github.com/mauri870/syscall) which is

> ... an effort to port the plan9 syscall command to Linux.

For example

```
$ ./syscall write 1 Hello$'\n'World$'\n' 12
Hello
World
$ ./syscall -o read 0 buf 5
xyz
xyz
$ ./syscall -ov getcwd buf 100
Syscall return: 23
/home/user/src/syscall
```

---

Another port is [oliwer/syscall](https://github.com/oliwer/syscall)

```
syscall [-<n>] name [args...] [, name [args...]]...
```

Example usage:

```
syscall open /my/file 1 0755 , write \$0 hello \#hello , close \$0
syscall open /dev/random 0 , echo \$0
```